# LocalBroadcastManager doesn't send message from service to activity

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to connect my service and activity, tried different approaches, but nothing worked for me.

I start Servise in SplashActivity, when the app launches. Then Service do some work in background, and when this work is done, `stopself()` method is calling in `onStartCommand()` in Service.

Also there is another activity where should be results from this background work. The problem, that i need to load data into Recyclerview only when work is done and Service is stopped. So I Tried to use `LocalBroadcastManager` and send message to the activity before `stopself()` method.

The problem is, activity doesn't get any messages from Service. Here is my code, it's from this answer on stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/7478869

Service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    helper = ItemDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    helper.clearTable(Contacts_Contract.CONTACT_TABLE_NAME);
    Set<ContactItem> setC = getContactList();
    for(ContactItem item: setC){
        helper.insertContacts(item);
    }
    editor.putBoolean(IS_CONTACTS_IMPORTED, true);
    editor.apply();


    Intent intent2 = new Intent("myevent");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent2.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent2);

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand: stopping service");
    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starts");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Register to receive messages.
    // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
    // with actions named "custom-event-name".
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("myevent"));


}

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.e("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Import completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have an `android:process` attribute on any of these components in the manifest? And are these all part of one app?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, this is one app. In manifest, the service has attribute: <service
            android:name=".broadcastreceivers.ImportContactsService"
            android:process=":importprocess" />

Answer (score 1):

Tactically, the reason why this does not work is that `LocalBroadcastManager` is local to a process, and you have two processes.

Strategically, having this code in a separate process is unnecessary and dangerous. For example, you are relying on `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`, which [has been deprecated for over two years](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) and never worked especially well in the first place.

Comment: how is MODE_MULTI_PROCESS in sharedpreferences connected with my problem with LocalBroadcastManager?

Comment: @BigCoach: You decided to implement a service (I do not know why) and have that service be in a separate process (I do not know why). Having the service be in a separate process is why `LocalBroadcastManager` is not working. My second paragraph is simply there to try to convince you that you should not be using a service in a separate process here.